# Find out the highest value

Tags: javascript

I have event scroll.
Scrolling down I get the values (scrollTop). For example, 10,11,12.
How can I write the maximum value in lastScrollTop?

For example, I scrolled down and reached the point (scrollTop = 12)
Then I started scrolling up. And I need to remember the value of 12 outside of the event.

```
var lastScrollTop;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
  var scroll = this.scrollTop;
  lastScrollTop = ?;
  console.log(scroll);
});
```

Comment: So you only want to set `lastScrollTop = scroll` *if* `scroll` is greater than `lastScrollTop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the value if you are at a greater scroll position.

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
  var scroll = window.scrollY;
  lastScrollTop = scroll > lastScrollTop ? scroll : lastScrollTop;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

lastScrollTop = (scroll > lastScrollTop) ? scroll : lastScrollTop;